# matplotlib.mathtext display a simple fraction (as image)

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

How do I create this mathematically expression in mathtext and store it as an image (png) for later use in a tkinter application?
(edit: it doesn't have to be matplotlib, any python library that can do the job would be fine by the way!)

Comment: Did you try googling "mathtext matplotlib"?

Comment: Jup, I wasnt able to figure it out. Is it even possible? I have read this to be exact: https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/mathtext_api.html

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is indeed to use matplotlib. You would put the mathtext as text into the figure and save it as png, limiting the saved region to the region of the text.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create MathText formula
formula = r"$\frac{15.118\times 100}{460.370} = 3.3 \%$"

#make a plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# add formula as text
tx = ax.text(0.5,0.5,formula, ha="center", va="center")
# turn axes off
ax.axis("off")

# draw the canvas, such that a renderer is defined
fig.canvas.draw()
# obtain the extent of the formula in inches
trans = tx.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
# save the figure, limited to the formula's extent
plt.savefig(__file__+".png", bbox_inches=trans)
```

The output would be

[image]

Comment: Excellent! How would you go about adding space between words in the fraction?
Like: formula = r"$\frac{'space>  <space + finansielle omkostninger \times 100}{460.370} = 3.3 \%$"

Comment: MathText works in a large range exactly like latex and accepts most latex commands. To [add a space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing) or to [add text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode) there are several different ways, of which you may chose the most convenient for you.